# different screen sizes with corona sdk

Tags: lua, size, screen, coronasdk, resolution

I am making my first iphone game using corona sdk and would like it to run on as many devices as possible (phones + tablets). However I am not sure how to deal with different screen sizes and resolutions. I developed my game for the iPhone 5 using corona simulator and it works fine on that device. When I tried it on lower resolution devices like the iPhone 4 I get 2 black rectangles on each side. I tried creating 2 different backgrounds with different resolutions and added this in my config.lua:

```
imageSuffix = {
       ["@2x"] = 2
}
```

However this does not seem to change anything... I am not sure what height and width I should set in content in the config.lua file and what heights and widths I should set for the backgrounds. I am sorry if these questions are stupid, I am just starting.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this name is a curse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you need to fully read up on config files and dynamic scaling.

The question is a little to broad as such I suggest you read this article about ["the ultimate config/modernizing the config"](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/10/modernizing-the-config-lua/).

> Some screens are wider while others are more narrow.  If we take
>   resolution out of the equation, its easier to visualize the screens.
>   Corona makes it easy to take resolution out of the picture using
>   Dynamic Scaling.  With Dynamic Scaling, you can use a common set of
>   screen coordinates and Corona will automatically scale the text and
>   graphics for different resolution screens.  It can scale upwards or
>   downwards depending on your starting point.  It also can substitute
>   higher resolution images when it needs to scale up. This is all
>   managed by a Lua file in your project folder called config.lua.
>
> Since available resolutions vary considerably, it’s helpful to use the
>   same scale for each device.  It doesn’t matter if you’re on an iPhone
>   3GS at 320×480 or a Retina iPad at 1536×2048, the location (0,0)
>   represents the top-left corner and (320,480), in vertical portrait
>   mode, is the bottom-right corner. The screen center is (160,240). 
>   Each point, in this case, is one pixel on a lower-resolution device
>   like the 3GS, which has a native screen resolution of 320×480, while
>   each point is four pixels on a Retina iPad. Don’t worry about the math
>   — Corona will handle it for you.
>
> Source: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/

This goes through the creation of a config file that fully utilize the dynamic scaling and image scaling.

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil( 480 / aspectRatio ),
      height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.ceil( 320 * aspectRatio ),
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

      imageSuffix = {
         ["@2"] = 1.8,
         ["@4"] = 3.6,
      },
   },
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You've been a lot of help to me!