# Making my game fitt for all screen sizes - corona

Tags: lua, height, size, screen, coronasdk

my game's frame is a little bigger then the screen. on galalxy s5/s4 it works good and also on iphone 5/6.
I am using this code for making the game's frame fit for all screen sizes:
config.lua:

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth

    application =
    {
    content =
    {
      width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 1080 or math.ceil( 1920 / aspectRatio ),
          height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 1920 or math.ceil( 1080 * aspectRatio ),
    scale = "letterbox",
    fps = 60,
    ...]
```

it dosent look perfectly good on nokia lumia, nexus 5(I have hided nevigation bar) and iphone 4 (that what i checked).
just a  little longer (the game is out  of the screen frame).
mabe someone can help me? i dont no what to do to make it work on all Devices.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to fully read up on config files and dynamic scaling.

The question is a little to broad as such I suggest you read this article about "the ultimate config/modernizing the config".

Some screens are wider while others are more narrow. If we take resolution out of the equation, its easier to visualize the screens. Corona makes it easy to take resolution out of the picture using Dynamic Scaling. With Dynamic Scaling, you can use a common set of screen coordinates and Corona will automatically scale the text and graphics for different resolution screens. It can scale upwards or downwards depending on your starting point. It also can substitute higher resolution images when it needs to scale up. This is all managed by a Lua file in your project folder called config.lua.

Since available resolutions vary considerably, it’s helpful to use the same scale for each device. It doesn’t matter if you’re on an iPhone 3GS at 320×480 or a Retina iPad at 1536×2048, the location (0,0) represents the top-left corner and (320,480), in vertical portrait mode, is the bottom-right corner. The screen center is (160,240). Each point, in this case, is one pixel on a lower-resolution device like the 3GS, which has a native screen resolution of 320×480, while each point is four pixels on a Retina iPad. Don’t worry about the math — Corona will handle it for you.

Source: http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/
This goes through the creation of a config file that fully utilize the dynamic scaling and image scaling.

```
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
 application = {
   content = {
    width = aspectRatio > 1.5 and 320 or math.ceil( 480 / aspectRatio ),
   height = aspectRatio < 1.5 and 480 or math.ceil( 320 * aspectRatio ),
    scale = "letterBox",
   fps = 30,

  imageSuffix = {
     ["@2"] = 1.8,
     ["@4"] = 3.6,
  },
 },
}
```

Pls refer here : [different screen sizes with corona sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004215/different-screen-sizes-with-corona-sdk)